# Add breakpoints in all places that fix REGEX (e.g. in all viewDidLoad methods)

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, xcode, breakpoints

Can anyone know if there is any automated way to add multiple breakpoints in XCode at the same time. In my case I want to add breakpoints in all `-viewDidLoad` or `-tableView:didSelecRowAtIndexPath:` methods by few clicks not using `cmd+shift+F`shortcut and set in in all (tens or even hundreds occurences).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using **lldb**

To break on any source code line in **current file** matching regex:

```
br se -p 'viewDidLoad'
```

Use `-f` to specify multiple files:

```
br se -f Foo.m -f Bar.m -f Baz.m -p 'viewDidLoad'
```

To break on *methods* or *functions* in **all files** matching regex:

```
br se -r 'view(Did|Will)Appear'
```

For more info, type `help breakpoint set` into the lldb console at the bottom of Xcode. Hope that helps.